# Change TMX map dynamically

Tags: android, andengine, pacman, tmx

I'm trying to develop pacman for Android. I am using **andengine** with tmx map but I'm having a bit of difficulty in managing the collection of balls ..

I initially tried to create an object for each ball, but 240 objects have halved my FPS.
Then I tried to insert the ball directly into tmx map and then later change the tile with the ball, with tile empty ..
how can I dynamically change the tile?

on TMXTiledMapExample there's:

```
`189: // tmxTile.setTextureRegion(null);` <-- Rubber-style removing of tiles =D but it doesn't work D:
```

Can you help me to find the best way?

ps: sorry for my bad english :)
pps: GLES2

Answer (score 1):

Andengine doesnt allow null tiles at least to my knowledge setting a tile to null will most likely give u a null pointer u can try filling it with a clear color or something that matches the background